# vgg16: TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, computer-science

work with medicala images, I use VGG16 for the classification of two classes, I remove the last layer (predictions (Dense)) and I add two layers, I had an accuracy of 71% during 200 epochs, I want to use my pre-training model to locate the areas in image with Grad CAM +++, so when I call my model, I got this error !!
How can I solve this problem? Is my method correct or not? please help

```
vgg16_model=keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
vgg16_model.layers.pop()`
model=Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='predic'))
from keras.optimizers import SGD
#model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

`import time`    `

```
start = time.time()
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_batches,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              steps_per_epoch=steps_train,
                              #callbacks=callbacks_list,
                              validation_data=valid_batches,
                              validation_steps=steps_valid,
                               shuffle=True)
end = time.time()

model = model(include_top=True, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3))
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 model = model(include_top=True, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3))
>
> TypeError: **call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Comment: This line makes no sense: 
model = model(include_top=True, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3)) Seems its just a typo, where model should be VGG16

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro no, in fact I want to use the weight of my model trained to locate the areas on which the CNN performs the classification
I made some changes on architecture vgg16, I trained on my database

I want use  Grad-CAM as a localization tool but I do not know how to insert my model withe his weights in Grad-CAM
i use this keras implementation of gradcam_plus_plus 
https://github.com/totti0223/gradcamplusplus

Comment: What is the line that I mentioned supposed to do? The error is there and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: that line suppose to call the model and his weights to use in Grad-CAM.  
this is the way used in keras  for calling  vgg16 or resnet50 or any other  model pre-trained 
so i was asking is this the same way? or how i can do it?

Comment: Those are the parameters you pass to the pretrained model classes, not to a general model. You already have a model instance that you should be able to use with gradcam.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro in fact I do not know how to use my model with gradcam,   I'm new to deep learning, and all the gradcam code use pretrained model, do you have any idea how it works? please help me